# Is an objects constructor called upon rehydration

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, constructor, isolatedstorage

I have an object that upon instantiation greats a unique id for itself via the constructor. My question may be silly but I cannot seem to find the answer.

Will the constructor be called upon rehydration from isolated storage? or is the constructor only called when using the 'new' keyword. My intention is not to have it called as I only want it to be called when instantiating for the first time.

Comment: binary or Xml serialization? Not that it matters necessarily, but I'm curious ...

Comment: Whatever is the default for isolated storage on windows phone 7 I am storing the object in IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor will be called during the deserialization process. It will create the object and then copy over the serialized properties/fields.

Comment: How does it deal with properties that are read only or private set?

Comment: My last comment is moot as I can just have logic check on the property and not in the constructor but its great to know this info, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is for .Net 4, not Silverlight, according to [MSDN: ISerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx), specifically:

> The ISerializable interface implies a
>   constructor with the signature
>   constructor (SerializationInfo
>   information, StreamingContext
>   context). At deserialization time, **the
>   current constructor is called** only
>   after the data in the
>   SerializationInfo has been
>   deserialized by the formatter. In
>   general, this constructor should be
>   protected if the class is not sealed.

... I wouldn't expect anything different on the Windows Phone.